# Is this a point of contact between Marxism and Heidegger?

Tags: ethics, heidegger, marx, marxism, authenticity

Is this a point of contact between Marxism and Heidegger?

Marx complains (bitterly) about **exploitation** by your - class - enemies

Heidegger complains about inauthenticity, which I might gloss as someone attempting to cheat you with fakery: an enemy, disguised as a friend, *exploits* you.

Do the two have the same ethical foil?

I think this is to ask whether the friendship of "das man" is false in the sense of others **actively cheating** you out of your individuality.

Comment: I suspect that since literature about Heidegger and Marx is scarce, and both are not exactly renowned for their contributions to ethics, that you will be hard-pressed to find something on that. But this looks like a good candidate for starters: https://nupress.northwestern.edu/content/heidegger-and-marx

Comment: interesting, less deconstructive than i would have thought. X with Y - exploratory - studies are often dull, for me, as if they're trying to reinvent things (and failing) @PhilipKlöcking

Comment: They are very different thinkers, and Heidegger was vehemently anti-marxist. I don't see a connection in your examples, and I wouldn't call Heidegger's inauthenticity a type of animosity or exploitation by others. More like being lost in the herd and forgetful of one's finite being. Perhaps the likeliest link would be in Hegelian "alienation," which is  explicitly adapted by Marx and can be seen as similar to existential inauthenticity.

Comment: @NelsonAlexander i would certainty argue that "alienation" of men from the product of their labour is exploitative, and would imagine that the term is too broad to make much of it. if you can show that hedeigger has nothing to do with being cheated *by others* then you should answer

Comment: @anon Your gloss of Heideggerian inauthenticity is rather unusual. I would think that the burden is on you to show that there is a reason to think there may be a connection, rather than on Nelson Alexander to show that there isn't. In other words, where in Heidegger's text do you find the support for your gloss?

Comment: that Heidegger's 'aletheia'  does not mean "truth" as a fact independent of us, how inauthenticity is of the "they self" and obscures the truth (not just of mortality), and he is concerned with honesty @transitionsynthesis

Comment: i guess you're right though @NelsonAlexander Heidegger is too idiosyncratic to worry "animosity or exploitation"

Comment: @anon Ok, but inauthenticity is an ontological structure of fallenness. It is not an "attempt" by "someone" to cheat you. I don't see what aletheia has to do with it.

Comment: ok well i've already agreed, don't see why you highlighted "attempt" or "someone", do they not figure in inauthenticity? @transitionsynthesis